# jQuery - wait for an element to be closed

Tags: jquery

I made a simple "popup" on my website.

```
function popup(message) {
  $("#popup").text(message);
  $("#popup").show();
  $("#popup").click(function() {
    $("#popup").hide();
  });
}
```

I want to display a few popups, one ofter the other. I want to have them declared as follows:

```
popup("Message 1");
popup("Message 2");
.
.
popup("Message n");
```

But I want the second popup to display after first popup was closed (by clicking on it).

So something like:

```
$("#popup").click(function() {
  // display the next popup
});
```

How can I make my code to wait untill the popup is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a callback argument that is called when the popup is closed:

```
function popup(message, onClose) {
  $("#popup").text(message);
  $("#popup").show();
  $("#popup").one('click', function() {
    $("#popup").hide(onClose);
  });
}
```

And open next popups in the callback function:

```
popup("Message 1", function () {
  popup("Message 2", function () {
    // ...
  });
});
```

I replaced `.click(` with `.one('click'` to make sure that the callback is called only once when the popup is closed. Otherwise one callback would be called many times (when each popup is closed).

[Demo](https://codepen.io/TheFinesse/pen/mGOPVJ?editors=1010)

---

Also you can use [jQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to make a more beautiful syntax for the popups chain:

```
function popup(message) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $("#popup").text(message);
  $("#popup").show();
  $("#popup").one('click', function() {
    $("#popup").hide(deferred.resolve);
  });
  return deferred.promise();
}

popup("Message 1")
  .then(function() { return popup("Message 2"); })
  .then(function() { return popup("Message 3"); })
  // ...
  .then(function() { return popup("Message n"); });
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/TheFinesse/pen/GXNZZp?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to have a look at [BootStrap's modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) to do this...

But the way you wish to call your messages is particular... And what's below could anyway be used along a Bootstrap modal.

So, the thing is that calling a `popup()` function **will not** wait. So you have to push all those messages in an array and wait for a click to "cycle" through them using an index.

See comments within the code.

```js
var messages = [];
var message_index = 0;
var popup_el = $("#popup");

function popup(message) {
  
  // Push the message in the array.
  messages.push(message);
  
  // If the popup element already is visible, stop here.
  if(popup_el.is(":visible")){
    return;
  }
  
  // Show the message (works on first... Then the click handler dos it.
  popup_el.text(message).show();
  
  // Click handler
  popup_el.click(function() {
    // Increment the array index
    message_index++;
    
    // If there is no more message to display, hide it... Else, disply the message
    (message_index>messages.length-1) ? $(this).hide() : $(this).text(messages[message_index]);
  });
}


popup("Message 1");

popup("Message 2");

popup("Message 3");

popup("Message 4");

popup("Message n");
```

```css
#popup{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup"></div>
```